# Angular и шаблон MVC...?

Tags: mvc, angular

Чуть меньше полгода назад вышел из колледжа и занимаюсь веб-разработкой.

Сейчас смотрел некоторые туториалы по Angular JS.
Структура приложения понятна, однако можно ли привести её под шаблон MVC? Кодил в Django и в Laravel и там все ясно - вот тебе контроллеры, роуты, модели, вьюшки - дерзай!
В Angular очень не привычно...
Мб MVC вовсе не подходит для Angular?

Answer (score -2):

ну как то так же можно

```
angular.module('app').component('name', {
    templateUrl:'',
    controller: function nameContriller () {

    }
})
```

типа контрролер отделно и вьюшка

Answer (score -2):

У Ангуляра отдельно components - view из MVC, то есть, всё то что прогружается на странице по итогу.
Controller - это controller,
Service - это model, в том случае, когда он используется для извлечения данных.
Не совсем ожидаемый Model-View-Controller, но тем не менее все ещё MVC.